# Print to a LAN printer from an Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, printing

We have label printers in our different offices and are attempting to create an Azure Function to manage printing for all of them. The problem is that our offices and Azure instance are all on different networks, and our label printers can only be connected to from their respective network.

Does anyone know a solution for this? I am currently exploring Azure Universal Print but I'm not sure if that is a viable solution.

Comment: Azure function cannot print to your local printer. You could have a service that runs on local office network, which receives message from Azure `SignalR` and then give print command to LAN printer.

Comment: It can print if you open things up but not advisable

Answer (score 0):

*As per the statement provided by @Anand Sowmithiran, Yes Azure Functions cannot print to your local printer.*
*Rather I would suggest you try with connecting printers to Azure Active Directory this will help you in managing printing from any of the network.*

*We have Azure Hybrid cloud printing which will connect to the Azure-AD joined devices to the On-prem printing infrastructure.*

[image]

*For More information check this [document](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/printing-to-on-prem-printers-from-azure-ad-joined-devices/ba-p/706423).*

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can implement a solution to enable Azure functions to print to local printers. Universal print is one option. In case your printer does not support Universal Print you need a [Print Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/universal-print/fundamentals/universal-print-connector-installation) application running in your local network.